# Чем заменить в предложении фразу "из-за того, что"

Tags: пунктуация

Собственно, предложение:

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо бы, чтобы Вы перечитывали то, что пишете... *"Чем опустить фразу?"* Хотела бы я увидеть ответ ))). Может, Вы хотели спросить, чем ее заменить? Заменить можно на синонимичный  союз *вследствие того что* или *так как.*

Где предполагается тире или двоеточие, я тоже не поняла. В любом случае, в предложении вполне достаточно имеющихся запятых. Дополнительных запятых не нужно.

---

Добавляю после комментария и исправлений в вопросе.

Вы хотите переделать сложноподчиненное предложение в бессоюзное. Можно, конечно, но Ваши варианты мне не нравятся. Получается, что вторая часть поясняет только смысл оборота. Вариант со скобками мне кажется более удачным. А что, в первоначальном виде оставить нельзя?